# iOS splash screen with buttons

Tags: xcode, ios, splash-screen

I am new to iOS dev. I've a splash screen and want to replace it with an initial view, I mean with an image and two buttons. How can I set up an initial view ? I'm using Xcode 4 with iOS 4. Here's my code...

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions { 

UIView *backgroundView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame: window.frame];
backgroundView.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
[window addSubview:backgroundView];
[backgroundView release];

// Override point for customization after application launch.

DataController *appController = [DataController sharedObject];

tabController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];

HomeViewController *hemView = [[HomeViewController alloc] init];
[hemView setTitle:@"Hem"];
hemView.tabBarItem.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"icon_home.png"];
UINavigationController *homeNavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:hemView];
[homeNavigationController.navigationBar setTintColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:(0.96) green:(0.96) blue:(0.96) alpha:0.0]];
[hemView release];


SearchViewController *sdkView = [[SearchViewController alloc] init];
[sdkView setTitle:@"Search"];
sdkView.tabBarItem.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"icon_search.png"];
UINavigationController *sdkNavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:sdkView];
[sdkNavigationController.navigationBar setTintColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:(0.96) green:(0.96) blue:(0.96) alpha:0.0]];
[sdkView release];



NSArray * arrayOfControllers = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:homeNavigationController, sdkNavigationController, nil];
tabController.viewControllers = arrayOfControllers;

SplashScreenViewController *controller = [[SplashScreenViewController alloc] init];
[tabController presentModalViewController:controller animated:YES];
[controller release];


[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
[window addSubview:tabController.view];


[homeNavigationController release];
[sdkNavigationController release];
[appController release];
return YES;
}
```

But this code doesn't show the splash screen , it takes me directly to the HomeViewController , help please .

Comment: The easiest way is to use Xcode's integrated Interface Builder. Follow Apple's developer tutorials if you're new to Xcode.

Answer (score 0):

(Warning, ARC based code ... don't forget to release)
I've did it like that:

First I put both `SplashScreenViewController` `*controller` and `tabController` as properties of `appDelegate`.

Then I change `didFinishLaunchingWithOption` to show only the `SplashScreenViewController`

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

    UIView *backgroundView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame: window.frame];
    backgroundView.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
    [window addSubview:backgroundView];
    [backgroundView release];

    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    DataController *appController = [DataController sharedObject];

    [self controller] = [[SplashScreenViewController alloc] init];

    [[self controller]setAppDelegate:self];
    self.window.rootViewController = self.controller;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

so, in your `SplashScreenViewController`, add a property appDelegate pointing to your Application `appDelegate`.

Then, do what you want on your splashscreen (login, button, etc...)
In this example, this is a simple login button. When you click on the button, it calls a function into your `appDelegate`

```
- (IBAction)loginButton:(id)sender 
{
    [[self appDelegate]setMainTabBarControllerOnScreen];
}
```

This function will now load the tabBarController and remove the splashcreen login screen

```
self.tabController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];

HomeViewController *hemView = [[HomeViewController alloc] init];
[hemView setTitle:@"Hem"];
hemView.tabBarItem.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"icon_home.png"];
UINavigationController *homeNavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:hemView];
[homeNavigationController.navigationBar setTintColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:(0.96) green:(0.96) blue:(0.96) alpha:0.0]];

SearchViewController *sdkView = [[SearchViewController alloc] init];
[sdkView setTitle:@"Search"];
sdkView.tabBarItem.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"icon_search.png"];
UINavigationController *sdkNavigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:sdkView];
[sdkNavigationController.navigationBar setTintColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:(0.96) green:(0.96) blue:(0.96) alpha:0.0]];

NSArray * arrayOfControllers = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:homeNavigationController, sdkNavigationController, nil];
self.tabController.viewControllers = arrayOfControllers;
```

And here is the trick

```
[[self window] addSubview:self.tabController.view];
[[self window]setRootViewController:[self tabController]];
[[[self viewController]view] removeFromSuperview];
```